# Golang Type Assertion Failure

Tags: go, types, casting, slice, assertion

In Golang,
I am trying to convert an Interface to Slice of Bytes.
Debugger clearly shows that it is a Slice of Bytes.

```
    // Check an Interface's Type.
    ifcType = reflect.TypeOf(ifc).Kind()

    // Array?
    if ifcType == reflect.Slice {

        // Get Type of Sub-Elements.
        ifcElementType = reflect.TypeOf(ifc).Elem().Kind()
        if ifcElementType == reflect.Uint8 {

            // Array of Bytes.
            // => 'bencode' Byte String.

            // Convert the Type.
            ba, ok = ifc.([]byte)
            if !ok {
                return nil, ErrTypeAssertion
            }
```

When I have checked that Interface's Type is Slice and Sub-Item's Type is Uint8, I do the Type Assertion. But for some Reason, it fails. How can that be ?

GoLand's Debugger Screenshot just after 'ok' Variable has become 'false':
http://imagehost.cc/image/v4403

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Reason.

That Slice of Bytes was really of 'ByteString' Type which really was a Slice of Bytes.
Why the Compiler does not understand that these are equal Types I can not understand.

I had to change the Field's Type from a Type Alias to simple '[]byte', and it now works.

Comment: It presumably was not a type alias then.